# Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup and Python : failed to extract text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i try to **scrape** a [website](http://engine.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak). But i failed to extract the description of each item. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://engine.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
puts =soup.find_all("div",{"class":"p3-search-item"})
for put in puts:
    title = put.find("div", {"class":"p3-title"}).text
    cat = put.find("div", {"class":"p3-category"}).text
    date = put.find("div", {"class":"search-result-item-meta"}).text
    link = put.find("a").get("href")
    put_response = requests.get(link)
    put_data = put_response.text
    put_soup = BeautifulSoup(put_data, "html.parser")
    put_description = put_soup.find("div",{"id": "modal-contents-pp"}).text
    print("Judul Putusan:", title, "\nKategori:", cat, "\nTanggal:", date, "\nLink:", link, "\nDescription:", put_description)
```

So i failed to extract the description.
The description only show blank and few words. The full description can be shown if we click each item's link.
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: It would seem that the links open pages that load via javascript so you'll need a solution that can execute javascript. Search StackOverflow for Selenium.

Comment: but i dont understand, when i inspect the web page, it clearly contains of div etc, i cant see if it uses javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the put_description field:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://engine.ddtc.co.id/putusan-pengadilan-pajak"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
puts =soup.find_all("div",{"class":"p3-search-item"})
for put in puts:
    title = put.find("div", {"class":"p3-title"}).text
    cat = put.find("div", {"class":"p3-category"}).text
    date = put.find("div", {"class":"search-result-item-meta"}).text
    link = put.find("a").get("href")
    put_response = requests.get(link)
    put_data = put_response.text
    put_soup = BeautifulSoup(put_data, "html.parser")
    put_description = put_soup.find("div",{"class": "p3-desc"}).text
    print("Judul Putusan:", title, "\nKategori:", cat, "\nTanggal:", date, "\nLink:", link, "\nDescription:", put_description)
```

Comment: it's not the p3-desc that i want to extract, but the description from after opening the link